# Image not appearing when using .transition

Tags: swift, image, swiftui

```
struct BEHOLD: View {
@State private var showdeatail = false
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Button(action: {
            showdeatail.toggle()
        }) {
            Text("S U M M O N\nH I M")
        }
        .frame(width: 100, height: 50)
        .background(Color.red)
        .cornerRadius(10)
        
        if showdeatail {
            Image("HIM")
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .transition(.scale)
            
        }
    }
}
```

So I'm trying to make this image appear when you hit a button and the code seems to be working except the Image seems to be invisible and I'm not sure why

Comment: If you don't include `if showdeatail` does it appear? In other words, does `Image("HIM")` resolve to a real image in your project?

Comment: Upon a second glance for some reason it isnt But its loading something since its shifting the Button

Comment: Well, you're using `frame(width: 100, height: 100)`, so I would expect it's shifting it by `100` points. What happens if you add `.resizable()` after `Image()`?

Comment: It changes nothing

Comment: I Also tried it on its own and its loading something but not showing anything since its shifting the button as stated before

Comment: Please verify the image name. Also check log No image named 'HIM' found in asset catalog for .....

Comment: So apparently the issue was that I had imported the Image incorrectly

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it would work!

```
 struct BEHOLD: View {
    
    @State private var showdeatail = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            Button(action: {
                showdeatail.toggle()
            }) {
                Text("S U M M O N\nH I M")
            }

            .background(Color.red)
            .cornerRadius(10)
            
            if showdeatail {
                Image(systemName: "person")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    .transition(.scale)
                
            }
        }
        .animation(.default, value: showdeatail)
    }
}
```